# Solving $AXB + X\odot C = D$ matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Can anyone see a way to solve this equation efficiently?

$$AXB + X\odot C = D$$

I tried a straightforward solution that involved vectorizing $X$ but that turned out too expensive for my application -- my matrices are all $d\times d$ with $d=1000$ so I'm seeing if there's a way to solve it at a cost comparable to $d\times d$ SVD.

$A$,$B$ are positive-semi-definite and $C$ may have a few zeros.

Comment: Have you tried solving the vectorized equation with an iterative method, such as GMRES? You can use the non-vectorized form to compute the matrix-vector product in $O(d^3), so your total cost would be comparable to SVD if the number of iterations is small. You might need a preconditioner though.

Comment: How many nonzeros are we talking about for $C$? Suppose you create $\widetilde{C}$ by replacing zero entries of $C$ with ones. Then would you say that the operator $M \mapsto M \odot (C - \widetilde{C})$ is low rank?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't work. This was because Hadamard product and matrix-matrix products are not associative with each other

Comment: Yeah that would make it a lot easier, I could just add a small constant to all zero entries and get approximate solution through sylvester

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I added "matrix-equations", correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: [Cross-posted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342639/solving-axb-x-odot-c-d).

Comment: Where it appears to have an answer. Please post on one site at a time only.

Comment: @Richard It does not look like a full answer, after a quick read.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this problem is not solvable in O(d^3). It comes from approximating T=E[xi,xj,xk,xl] in terms of lower order moments, then trying to solve TX=G. I found that even computing ||T||^2 needs more than O(d^3) operations

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\KR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}} \def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\KR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Write the problem as a matrix function
$$\eqalign{
F &= \BR{AXB + C\odot X - D} \;\doteq\; f(X) \\
}$$
then use $F$ to create a scalar *sum-of-squares* objective function
$$\eqalign{
\tfrac 12\,\|F\|^2 \;=\; \tfrac 12\,F:F \;\doteq\; \phi(X) \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad\big({\rm Frobenius\:norm}\big) \\
}$$
Calculate the gradient of $\phi$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= F:dF \\
 &= F:\LR{A\,dX\,B + C\odot dX} \\
 &= \LR{A^TFB^T + C\odot F}:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= \LR{A^TFB^T + C\odot F} \;\doteq\; g(X) \\
}$$
Use this gradient expression in your favorite gradient descent algorithm. I prefer Barzilai-Borwein for its speed and simplicity.

Initialize with the starting guess
$$\eqalign{
X_0 &= random \\
G_0 &= g(X_0) \\
\phi_0 &= \tfrac 12\,\|f(X_0)\|^2 \\
X_1 &= X_0 - \fracLR{0.05\cdot\phi_0}{G_0:G_0}G_0
\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
k &= 1 \\
}$$
and iterate until the convergence is satisfactory
$$\eqalign{
G_k &= g(X_k) \\
X_{k+1}
 &= X_k
  - \fracLR{\LR{X_k-X_{k-1}}:\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}}
           {\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}:\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}} G_k \\
k &= k+1 \\
}$$